# jQuery Click the random anchor tag from the series of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have five anchor tags. I want to make a loop in which after every 5 sec next random tag should be clicked using Jquery. it should be unlimited.

[image: Five Anchor tags]

Here is my Html code.

```
<ul class="nav-tabs-slideshow">
            <li><a href="#panel-1"><strong>Study with umdc</strong><br />
                <span>Study Hard. Play Hard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#panel-2"><strong>Messages</strong><br />
                <span>We prepare you to wild world</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#panel-3"><strong>Vision & Mission</strong><br />
                <span>Discovery &amp; Innovation</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#panel-4"><strong>Newsroom</strong><br />
                <span>Latest campus news update</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#panel-5"><strong>Events</strong><br />
                <span>Schedule of our activity</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Every kind of Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the link.

Comment: Please reconsider this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// For Random Click

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  
  
  
  
  jQuery(document).on({
   mouseenter: function () {
    jQuery('.nav-tabs-slideshow').addClass('mouseenter1');
   },
 
   mouseleave: function () {
    jQuery('.nav-tabs-slideshow').removeClass('mouseenter1');
   }
  }, '.nav-tabs-slideshow');
  
  setInterval(function(){
   
   if(!jQuery('.nav-tabs-slideshow').hasClass('mouseenter1')){
    click1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * jQuery('.nav-tabs-slideshow li').length));   console.log(click1);// for Check
    jQuery('.nav-tabs-slideshow li:eq( '+click1+' ) a').trigger('click');
    jQuery('.nav-tabs-slideshow li:eq( '+click1+' ) a').css({'color':'red'});
   }
    
   
  },1000);
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-tabs-slideshow">
      <li><a href="#panel-1"><strong>Study with umdc</strong><br />
        <span>Study Hard. Play Hard</span> </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#panel-2"><strong>Messages</strong><br />
        <span>We prepare you to wild world</span> </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#panel-3"><strong>Vision & Mission</strong><br />
        <span>Discovery &amp; Innovation</span> </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#panel-4"><strong>Newsroom</strong><br />
        <span>Latest campus news update</span> </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#panel-5"><strong>Events</strong><br />
        <span>Schedule of our activity</span> </a> </li>
    </ul>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  
  var click1 = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
   if(jQuery('.nav-tabs-slideshow li').length == click1)
   {
    click1 = 0; 
   }   
   jQuery('.nav-tabs-slideshow li:eq( '+click1+' ) a').trigger('click');
   jQuery('.nav-tabs-slideshow li:eq( '+click1+' ) a').css({'color':'red'});// this is only for demo
   click1 ++; 
   
  },5000);
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-tabs-slideshow">
  <li><a href="#panel-1"><strong>Study with umdc</strong><br />
    <span>Study Hard. Play Hard</span> </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#panel-2"><strong>Messages</strong><br />
    <span>We prepare you to wild world</span> </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#panel-3"><strong>Vision & Mission</strong><br />
    <span>Discovery &amp; Innovation</span> </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#panel-4"><strong>Newsroom</strong><br />
    <span>Latest campus news update</span> </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#panel-5"><strong>Events</strong><br />
    <span>Schedule of our activity</span> </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mansukh Khandhar.
can i stop this loop on mouse hover.
Actually i have 5 images like slider. and one image is shown on click.  i want to stop this loop on mouse hover on image.

Comment: yes ... but if you have live URL so i can understand easy

Comment: i am working on local. sorry for this. Do you understand what i want?

Comment: check now edit snippet

Comment: `<div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="panel-1" style="background:url(images/slide-4.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0">
</div>
<div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="panel-2" style="background:url(images/slide-4.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0">
</div>
<div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="panel-3" style="background:url(images/slide-4.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0">
</div>
<div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="panel-4" style="background:url(images/slide-4.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0">
</div>
<div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="panel-5" style="background:url(images/slide-4.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0">
</div>`
i have these 5 div. I want to stop on these div's mouse hover.

Comment: give me up vote to increase my reputation